# ntoskrnl.exe using hard drive heavily

Tags: windows-8, ntoskrnl.exe

For several days, my Windows 8 computer has experiences an issue where the hard drive is used extremely heavily by the process `ntosknrl.exe` for about an hour after I turn it on. This makes all of my programs run slowly and makes some of them unusable altogether.

This is a screenshot of Task Manager:

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager. The process "System" is listed as read/writing 24.8 MB/s to the hard drive]

When I right-click -> Properties on System, I get this:

[image: The properties window shows that a program called "ntoskrnl.exe" is what's using the hard drive]

How can I find out what is causing this behavior? What can I do about it?

Comment: run resource Monitor, go to the Disk tab and look which files the kernel/system accesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process Monitor from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) should let you find out more information about what is acting up. To use it start it up as Admin and double click System to bring up it's properties. From there select the "Threads" tab and it will show you the stack as well as which module is staying busy.